# Custom views in Laravel 9 + Jetstream won't load without testing first

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit

I have a new project I created recently using the latest Laravel 9 and Jetstream with Livewire. I've created some migrations and seeders and they run perfectly with Artisan.

Now I'm ready to start creating my homepage. I create a brand-new file called `index.blade.php` in the `resources/views` directory. I give it the contents of "Hello World." That's it. No boilerplate, no HTML, nothing. I update the main `/` route to point to `index` instead of `welcome`. I then create a Feature Test to make sure that getting the `/` route returns a status code of `200`. It runs great. The page also loads fine in a browser displaying the "Hello World" text.

Now comes the part where I get confused. I change the "Hello World" text to just say "Hello". Refreshing the browser, I get the following message:

[image: Permission denied?]

If I run the same Feature Test again, it still passes fine. Then, when I refresh the browser again *after* having run the test, it loads!

I have tried out many different procedures, but it seems like the page simply will not load whenever I make *any* change to it at all. However, any time I run the Feature Test, *then* reload the page in the browser, it'll show up fine. For reference, here's the test:

```php
<?php

namespace Tests\Feature;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\RefreshDatabase;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\WithFaker;
use Tests\TestCase;

class AppTest extends TestCase
{
    /**
     * Testing that the app's main page loads successfully.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function test_app_home_page_loads_successfully(): void
    {
        $response = $this->get('/');

        $response->assertStatus(200);
    }
}
```

What on earth is causing this odd behavior?

Comment: Are you accessing the site via localhost through php artisan serve or apache? If the later, make sure apache has permissions on that folder. storage should be 0755

Comment: as @IGP mentioned, the error is pretty clear, your web server does not have access to `storage/framework/views`, so please give the right permissions or (if it is local) just do `chmod 777 storage -r`

Comment: @IGP I am using Laravel Sail. And the `storage` directory is 0755, as well as its subdirectories (`app`, `debugbar`, `framework`, and `logs`).

Comment: @matiaslauriti 0777 seems incredibly insecure. Besides, how would changing one file in the `resources/views` directory affect the `storage` directory's permissions?

Comment: @Sturm as I previously said, if it is local, just do `chmod 777`, it doesn't matter, unless you are truly concerned of security issues even in local. If that is the case, you just need to have permissions to the `storage` folder in general with the user executing PHP (web server in this case)

Answer (score 1):

As @IGP and @matiaslauriti pointed out in the comments, there is clearly a permissions issue with `storage/framework/views`. However, it is not with the directory itself, just a single file (out of dozens) in that directory.

I do not know how or why, but that one file (`83b9b...`) had an owner:group of "root:root". The rest of the files in that directory are owned by me and my group.

What makes this odd is that this stays true even when I run the Feature Test, so I do not know why running that Feature Test causes the view to load fine even while that file is still owned by "root:root".

Manually changing that file's owner:group does, indeed, fix the issue. My only concern now is not knowing how it got changed in the first place and, thus, not knowing how to prevent this from happening again in the future. If anyone has any ideas, I'm open. For now, however, I'll go ahead and close this.

Thank you, @IGP and @matiaslauriti.

Comment: I am not sure what experience you have with Laravel, but if you have any issues with `storage`, it is 99% most of the time related to permissions (either user don't have permissions or the file/folder is using `root`). In your case, I have no idea how it ended up using `root:root`, but it should have nothing to do with `tests`. Maybe you run a command outside `sail` and with root?

Comment: You ran a command that created that cached view (as a side effect) with the root user. That's how the view got created. Perhaps you were running tests as the root user, and that view had not been cached yet.